# How can I store and search multiple IPv4 and IPv6 subnets in elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I would like to store IPv4 and IPv6 subnets (CIDR format) in elasticsearch and search for IP address (/32 and /128) inclusion in them.

Sadly, elasticsearch (up to 1.5.1) only has primitive types and an IPv4 type, which can only be used to store /32 addresses, not subnets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch provides (signed) integer type, which matches IPv4 and long, which can be used to store, index and search IPv6 addresses, split into two 64 bit integers.

Sample python code for creating the elasticsearch index, mapping, storing and searching follows:

```
import ipaddr
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(['http://localhost:9200'])
pm = es.indices.put_mapping

es.indices.delete(index='ips', ignore=[400, 404])
es.indices.create(index='ips', ignore=400)

pm(index='ips', doc_type='ip',
   body={
         "ip":{
               "properties":{
                             "ipv4":{"type":"nested",
                                     "properties":{
                                                   "first":{"type":"integer" },
                                                   "last":{"type":"integer" }
                                                   }
                                    },
                             "ipv6":{"type":"nested",
                                     "properties":{
                                                   "lofirst":{"type":"long" },
                                                   "lolast":{"type":"long" },
                                                   "hifirst":{"type":"long" },
                                                   "hilast":{"type":"long" }
                                                   }
                                    }
                           }
            }
     }
)

def cidrtoes(ip):
    '''
    Convert IP address or network to ES-stored format

    :param ip: IPv4 or IPv6 address or network in CIDR notation
    :returns: dictionary which can be added to ES document
    '''
    ipnet = ipaddr.IPNetwork(ip)
    if ipnet.version == 4:
        s = {'first':int(ipnet) - 2 ** 31,
             'last':int(ipnet[-1]) - 2 ** 31}
    elif ipnet.version == 6:
        s = {'lofirst':(int(ipnet) & 2 ** 64 - 1) - 2 ** 63,
             'lolast':(int(ipnet[-1]) & 2 ** 64 - 1) - 2 ** 63,
             'hifirst':(int(ipnet) >> 64) - 2 ** 63,
             'hilast':(int(ipnet[-1]) >> 64) - 2 ** 63}
    return s

def ip4toes(address):
    '''
    Convert IPv4 address to ES-stored format

    :param address: IPv4 address
    :returns: IPv4 converted to signed integer
    '''
    ip = ipaddr.IPAddress(address)
    return int(ip) - 2 ** 31

def ip6toes(address):
    '''
    Convert IPv6 address to ES-stored format

    :param address: IPv6 address
    :returns: IPv6 address converted to low and high 64 bit signed integers
    '''
    ip = ipaddr.IPAddress(address)
    return [(int(ip) & 2 ** 64 - 1) - 2 ** 63, (int(ip) >> 64) - 2 ** 63 ] 

doc = {'ipv4':[cidrtoes('0.0.0.0/24'), cidrtoes('0.0.1.0/24'), cidrtoes('255.255.255.255')],
       'ipv6':[cidrtoes('::/64'), cidrtoes('1::/64'), cidrtoes('2::3')],
       }

es.index(index="ips", doc_type="ip", body=doc)
es.indices.flush(index="ips")


# IPv4 query
ip = '0.0.1.0'
searchip = ip4toes(ip)

s = es.search(index='ips', doc_type='ip', body=
{"query":{
          "filtered":{
                      "filter":{'nested':{
                                          'path':'ipv4',
                                          'filter':{
                                                    'and':[
                                                           {"range": {"first": {'lte':searchip}}},
                                                           {"range": {"last": {'gte':searchip}}},
                                                           ]
                                                    }
                                          }
                                }
                      }
          }
          }
              )

print "IPv4 result", s

# IPv6 query
ip = '2::3'
lo = ip6toes(ip)[0]
hi = ip6toes(ip)[1]

s = es.search(index='ips', doc_type='ip', body=
{"query":{
          "filtered":{
                      "filter":{'nested':{
                                          'path':'ipv6',
                                          'filter':{
                                                    'and':[
                                                           {"range": {"lofirst": {'lte':lo}}},
                                                           {"range": {"lolast": {'gte':lo}}},
                                                           {"range": {"hifirst": {'lte':hi}}},
                                                           {"range": {"hilast": {'gte':hi}}},
                                                           ]
                                                    }
                                          }
                                }
                      }
          }
          }
              )

print "IPv6 result", s
```

Comment: Hi Why didn't you use predefine IP type of elasticsearch ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ip-type.html

Comment: Several reasons:
1. it's only IPv4 and I need IPv6 too
2. I need IP inclusion queries (in what documents are 192.168.0.1 in?) in CIDR ranges (192.168.0.0/24), which is not possible with the build in type

Comment: Ok thanks .Correct if I'm wrong , but according to the documentation here :https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-iprange-aggregation.html   it seems possible . I didn't try it , maybe I'm confused .